# How to update state in React App when something happens on server side

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I have a small react app I've built that displays different entries in my mongoDB and then has filters, so it only shows what you're looking for.

In order to get the entries I have a js listener listening to an outside source and then adding them to MongoDB. Then I have my React App send a get request to my express app, which pulls the data from MongoDB and updates state on each refresh and grab all the entries.

I want the state to update everytime a new entry is added to MongoDB, so the user doesn't have to refresh and gets real time data.

Is there anyway I can call the useEffect function from the server side file or is there some way I can detect inside the react app when new data is added?

Comment: maybe you can try to look at websockets with https://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do a call on pageload to get the current data, then do subsequent calls on a set time interval and compare the length of the new call with the current calls, only saving data if there is a difference.